# How to install python-Levenshtein or other C/C++ packages on Win 7 64 bit

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, windows-7-x64, python-module

This is driving me completely nuts. I have looked at several answers to questions relating to this, but when I try the solutions non works.
First I tried a simple
*pip install python-Levenshtein*.   This 
this produced a lot of spam ending with *Unable to find vcvarsall.bat*Searching on that suggested I need to install Visual C++ 10.0; but when I tried that it errored out as apparently I already have a newer version installed. 
Then I found answers based on something called 'wheel'. This page [python libs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein) lists 8 .whl files for this module with NO explanation as to what each one is for.  I tried the first two and got the same response on each: *...whl  is not a supported wheel on this platform*

What I need is simple directions, that the proverbial small child could understand, as to how to install this module.

I am running Python 3.3, on a Win 7 64 bit machine. (I also have Python 2.7 and 2.4 installed but those are for other projects).  I do not use C++ directly for anything so have no knowledge of how its installed on my machine, I imagine it was either part of the OS or came with Python or some other package.  It seems to me that a Python module that relies on a C++ runtime would require the user to have any knowledge of C++ and would be completely 'self-contained'.  So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have win10 64 bit python 3.5 I have installed python-Levenshtein (0.12.0) using Visual studio 14. But there are compiled binaries already.

[python-levensthtein](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein)

Comment: Yes those are what I tried to install, well the 1st 2.  After getting the identical error on the 1st two (see the Qu) I gave up.

Comment: ok so now i must confess my ignorance, i thought thats what whl files were , some form of packaged object file (and other info probably ).

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is for those who like me need basic step-by-step. While I found a number of bits of the puzzle in other answers and pip / wheel documentation, I didn't find a complete step-by-step.  It uses 'wheels' which based on this experience seems to be simpler or more robust than the other methods.).

While I still don't know how to fix the C++ issue raised by simple pip install, I was able to do it using wheel. 
What I eventually figured out is how to parse the file names in [Python wheel object libs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs).   (The Fine Manual glossed over this).   The -cp*nn*- part of the name is the Python version number - cp33 for Python 3.3.   *win32* was pretty clear so I had figured out *win amd64* was for 64 bit systems though I've no idea what *amd* means.

So for Python 3.3 on a Windows 64 bit system the file I needed was
 *python Levenshtein-0.12.0-cp33-none-win amd64.whl*
  [I still don't know the significance of *none*, the Fine Manual is silent on that too.  Perhaps it means nothing...]

Step by step the process was:

- From [python Levenshtein wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein) download the relevant .whl 
  (*python_Levenshtein-0.12.0-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl* in my case)
- Create a *wheels* directory (or whatever name you like) under the Python33 directory (*Python33/wheels*)
- copy or move the .whl file from download folder to the wheels folder.
- Create a .bat file in Python33 directory, eg ...*Python33/piplev.bat* with the following lines (assuming *\Python33* is the root dir for Python)

> cd \Python33
>
> pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=wheels
>   wheels/python_Levenshtein-0.12.0-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl

- double click on the .bat file.
- You should get output like this in the cmd window:

> C:\Python33>
>  C:\Python33>pip install --use-wheel --no-index
>   --find-wheels wheels/python_Levenshtein-0.12.0-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl
> Ignoring
>   indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
> Processing
>   c:\python33\wheels\python_levenshtein-0.12.0-cp33-none-win_amd64.
>   whl
> Installing collected packages: python-Levenshtein
>   Successfully installed python-Levenshtein-0.12.0

Actually since I will likely want to install other packages with C++ I components, I made a generalised bat file *pipwheel.bat*:

> cd \Python33
>
> pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=wheels wheels/%1.whl

and then instead of double clicking the bat file I just open a cmd: window and type

> pipwheel package-name

(The root directory for Python - Python33 should by in the windows path, if it isnt you should first navigate to the Python33 directory)